# quiz.map is not iterable - React

Tags: reactjs

Im making a self-project - a quiz app.

It gets random strings from an api which generates a random object of 5 questions, including correct answers and wrong answers and the like .

```
function App() {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState({});
  const [resetGame, setNewGame] = React.useState(false);
  const [showStartMenu, setStartMenu] = React.useState(true);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setStartMenu(!showStartMenu)
  }

  function getQuizDetails(){
  fetch(`https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=5&category=9`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setQuiz(data["results"]))
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    getQuizDetails();
  }, [resetGame])

  //const quizJson = JSON.stringify(quiz, null, 0);
  const questions = quiz.map(x => x);



  return (
    <main>

      {!showStartMenu && <button onClick={toggleMenu}>Main Menu (For debug purposes only) </button>}
      {showStartMenu && <Start toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />}
      {!showStartMenu && <pre>{JSON.stringify(questions, null, 2)}</pre>}

    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But for some reason, when I try to map over the object, it doesnt work , rather it returns an error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: quiz.map is not a function
    at App (App.jsx:26:26)
```

Any way to approach this issue ? I'd like help rather than som1 pointing to some article or the like.

Note:- It works fine when I dont map or do anything and just `refer` to the `quiz` state. But I need to find a way to access the stuff like question, answer and stuff, so yea.

Here is the repl.it link if you need to see full source code.
[Quiz App - Replit](https://replit.com/@oku12xy/Quiz-App#src/App.jsx)

*I typed this in a hurry so feel free to ask what I should elaborate on .*

I found something interesting

When I do

```
  const questions = quiz.map(x => x);
```

map it seems to work.

However when I try

```js
  const questions = quiz.map(x => {
    return <Quiz questions={x["question"]} />
  });
```

It returns the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map()` is for arrays.  But `quiz` is not an array, it's an empty object:

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState({});
```

You may *later* set it to an array after fetching data.  But its initial state is an object.  If you instead want that state to be an array, make it an array:

```
const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you set quiz initial state as `Object`: `{}`, instead set it as `Array`: `[]`

From

```js
const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState({});
```

To

```js
const [quiz, setQuiz] = React.useState([]);
```